# MySql Right Outer Join with Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

`pd_tprofessional`, `pd_tpreference` and `pd_tprofessional_preference`.

`pd_tprofessional` and `pd_tpreference` have unique id (`fkprofessional` and `fkpreference`, respectively).

`pd_tprofessional_preference` has 3 columns: `fkpreference`, `patientpreference_selected`, `fkprofessional`

What I am trying to do is write a query that will get all the all `pd_tpreference` and return `patientpreference_selected` as 1 or 0 based on if `fkprofessional` is 13 and `pd_tprofessional_preference` with that `fkprofessional` exists.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT patientpreference_selected, fkprofessional, pkpreference, preference_name 
FROM pd_tprofessional_preference 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN pd_tpreference 
     ON pd_tpreference.pkpreference = pd_tprofessional_preference.fkpreference
```

This query gives me all the `pd_tpreference` by right outer joining them with `pd_tprofessional_preference`, now I am stuck on returning  `patientpreference_selected` as 1 or 0 based if that record exists in `pd_tprofessional_preference` when the `fkprofessional` is 13 with the `fkpreference`. I really hope this makes sense.

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Conventional and easily readable way is using `Left Join`. You can do a left-join from the `pd_tpreference` table to the `pd_tprofessional_preference` table.
- In the join `ON` condition, specify the condition that `fkprofessional = 13`.
- You can use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to handle the case when there is no match found in the `pd_tprofessional_preference` table.
- In multi-table queries, it is advisable to use Aliasing for code clarity and avoiding ambiguous behaviour.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  pref_t.fkpreference, 
  pref_t.preference_name, 
  map_t.fkprofessional, 
  COALESCE(map_t.patientpreference_selected, 0) AS patientpreference_selected
FROM pd_tpreference AS pref_t
LEFT JOIN pd_tprofessional_preference AS map_t
  ON map_t.fkpreference = pref_t.fkpreference AND 
     map_t.fkprofessional = 13
```

Comment: I get this error: Unknown column 'pt.pkpreference' in 'field list'

Comment: @user979331 I took this column name from your problem statement. Anyways, changed it to `fkpreference`